# Change content of one div when hovering on another in a different place

Tags: javascript, css, hover

Please help, I am trying to change the content in one div when mouse over on image in another div. Im trying to use this:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// icons
$('#iconone img').mouseover(function(){
    $('#stop').css('display', 'inline-block');

});
$('#iconone img').mouseout(function(){
    $('#stop').css('display', 'inline-block');
});

// box 2
$('#icontwo img').mouseover(function(){
    $('#stop').css('display', 'none');
    $('#shop').css('display', 'inline-block');
});
$('#icontwo img').mouseout(function(){
    $('#stop').css('display', 'none');
    $('#shop').css('display', 'inline-block');
});

// box 3
$('#iconthree img').mouseover(function(){
    $('#stop').css('display', 'none');
    $('#shop').css('display', 'none');
    $('#select').css('display', 'inline-block');
});
$('#iconthree img').mouseout(function(){
   $('#stop').css('display', 'none');
    $('#shop').css('display', 'none');
    $('#select').css('display', 'inline-block');
});
});
</script>
```

If anyone could help with this I would be very gratefull! Thanks guys :D

Comment: Can you post a Fiddle - jsfiddle.net. This code looks like it could definitely be re-factored.

Comment: That doesnt seem to be working :( my test site is seeitliveonline.co.uk/dcreatives you will see what i want to try and achieve is when i hover over the 3 icons the content in the purple box to the left changes. Thanks for your help so far :D

Comment: You're referencing an `ID` in your jQuery `$('#iconthree`, but you're using classes on the page, `<div class="iconone">`

Comment: Hi Nick, I have changed that now but still no joy :( is the code right? (i have changed everything to a class now by the way as i thought it was the # that was making it not work)

Comment: Also, you've got your script inside the `<!--[if lt IE 9]>` code block, so it's only going to run on `<= 8`

Answer (score 1):

You may just want to use `hover` ?
http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Example:
http://jsbin.com/kodiy/1/

```
var div1, div2;

div1 = $('.div1');

div2 = $('.div2');

div1.hover(function() {
  div2.hide();
}, function() {
  div2.show();
});
```

Comment: That doesnt seem to be working :( 

my test site is http://www.seeitliveonline.co.uk/dcreatives/ you will see what i want to try and achieve is when i hover over the 3 icons the content in the purple box to the left changes.

Thanks for your help so far :D

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this: **[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WtHEk/)**

```
$("a").hover(

  function() {

    var $this =  $(this).data("content");
    var $content =  $('#content .content');

     $content.hide();
     $('.' + $this).fadeIn(300);

  }, function() {
     $content.hide();
  }

);
```

HTML:

```
    <a href="#" data-content="content1">icon1</a>
    <a href="#" data-content="content2">icon2</a>
    <a href="#" data-content="content3">icon3</a>

    <div id="content">
        <div class="content active content1">content1</div>
        <div class="content content2">content2</div>
        <div class="content content3">content3</div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#content .content.active { display:block;}
#content .content { display:none;}
```

Comment: Nope still not working ? i have checked the code line by line :( im not sure what im doing wrong ? p.s Nick thanks for helping :D